# How can I set selenium chrome driver typing speed?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests

I have a ui test that uses selenium chrome driver. I want to set the form filling speed to be slower. I have googled but couldn't see how.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Selenium 1 you can use [setSpeed](http://release.openqa.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSelenium.SetSpeed.html) method, in Selenium 2 (aka WebDriver) is, unfortunately, no option like this, at best you can use [Implicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits). However is not really recommended to slow down the Selenium for all tests, you should add waits only for tests which really need to wait for some action to complete.